# A problem on almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence of random variables defined on the standard unit interval probability space : 
$$X_n  =
\begin{cases}
  2^n & \text{when}  \quad \frac{1}{2^n} \leq \omega \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}};  \\
   0  & \mbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Is $\{X_n\}$ convergent in a almost sure sense ?

I think it is not, it converges in probabilistic sense. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $\{X_n\}$ actually converges pointwise to $0$, because for each $\omega$, there is an integer $N(\omega)$ for which $X_n(\omega)=0$ whenever $n\geqslant N(\omega)$.

In particular, it does converge to $0$ in probability.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct and I just want to make it more clear.I assume here you mean $\omega$ drawn from [0,1].

First, yes, it is almost sure convergent to 0.

For any number $\omega$ drawn from [0,1], you can always let n large enough so that $X_n$ is 0 UNLESS $\omega$ is 0.

Be definition, $ X_n \xrightarrow{a.s} X \equiv Pr(\omega \in \Omega: lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n(s) = X(s) \, ) = 1
$

Here Pr([0,1] \ {0}) = 1

FYI, a.s. convergent implies convergent in probability so this also converges in p.

Another way to show this is to use Borel-Cantelli Lemma:

Lemma: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon ) < \infty \Longrightarrow X_n \xrightarrow{a.s} X$

Here $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$ is finite so it should be convergent a.s.